# Can I use Google detection API to detect QR code in an image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api, cloud-document-ai

Is it possible to detect a QR code in an image that is in a PDF document with Google API? I just see this page: [Google Objects Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview) [Invoice Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_invoice-processor) processor does extract Barcodes and some QR codes when using processor version `pretrained-invoice-v1.3-2022-07-15` and later.

Refer to [Send a processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request) and [Handling the processing response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#entities_nested_entities_and_normalized_values) for information on using the API.

The Barcode/QR code information is stored in the [`Barcode`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#barcode) field of the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) output object.

---

FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)